# How to compare day/month/year in C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, date, comparison

I have a program that asks the user to input to dates then it displays which one is more recent I've done it like this

```
if (year1>year2 || month1>month2 || day1>day2)
    return -1;

if (year1<year2 || month1<month2 || day1<day2)
    return +1;
```

but the output is not quite correct.

Comment: Right, your logic is wrong, and this has nothing to do with C++. Just think it through. What you need is a lexicographical comparison of year, month and day, in that order.

Comment: Have you tried writing out a few sample dates and trying the logic out yourself? Compare 2013-12-31, 2014-01-01.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a much more complicated check than that:

```
if (year1 > year2)
    return -1;
else if (year1 < year2)
    return +1;

if (month1 > month2)
    return -1;
else if (month1 < month2)
    return +1;

if (day1 > day2)
    return -1;
else if (day1 < day2)
    return +1;

return 0;
```

NOTE: Returning `-1` for *first is greater than second* seems counter-intuititive to me, however I have followed the semantics provided by the OP.

Comment: Probably a good idea to show writing the whole thing in terms of a single comparison operator, probably operator <.

Comment: @kfsone Agreed, however the OP doesn't provide enough context for the test.  So I provided a *drop-in* replacement.

Comment: It's nice that you've also provided a return for the case where the dates are identical.

Comment: @Rob Thanks.  I think the OP has the `-1` and `+1` back-to-front, however.  But I have followed the code he provided.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a clean way to do it:

```
#include <tuple> // for std::tie

auto date1 = std::tie(year1, month1, day1);
auto date2 = std::tie(year2, month2, day2);

if (date1 == date2)
  return 0;

return (date1 < date2) ? -1 : 1;
```

The comparisons of `std::tie` objects are lexicographical, so this returns `-1` if `date1` is less than `date2`, `0` if they are the same, and `1` if `date1` is greater than `date2`.

You might be better off defining your own `date` type (or use `boost::datetime`).

```
struct Date
{
  unsigned year;
  unsigned month;
  unsigned day;
};

bool operator<(const Date& lhs, const Date& rhs)
{
  return std::tie(lhs.year, lhs.month, lhs.day) < 
         std::tie(rhs.year, rhs.month, rhs.day);
}

bool operator>(const Date& lhs, const Date& rhs) { .... }

bool operator==(const Date& lhs, const Date& rhs) { .... }

int date_cmp(const Date& lhs, const Date& rhs) 
{
  // use operators above to return -1, 0, 1 accordingly
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
if (year1>year2 || month1>month2 || day1>day2)
    return -1;
```

tests if *any one* of the three conditions is true. So, if year1 is higher than year 2, or month1 is higher than month2. Lets stop there. Consider

```
year1 = 2013, month1 = 12, day1 = 31;
year2 = 2014, month2 = 1, day1 = 1;
```

We know that, infact, year2 is a higher value, but what happens is

```
is year1 > year2? no
ok, but is month1 > month2? yes
```

This makes it look like the first year is a higher value, but it's not, it just a higher month value.

As you get further into C++ you'll find that it's a good idea to try and adopt a convention of making all your comparisons use a single operator (< or >), when you reach a point where you are working with operators you'll understand why.

```
if (year2 < year1)
    return 1;
// we reach this line when year1 <= year2
if (year1 < year2) // elimnate the < case
    return -1;

// having eliminated both non-matches,
// we know that by reaching point that both
// dates have the same year. Now repeat for
// the month value.
if (month2 < month1)
    return 1;
if (month1 < month2)
    return -1;

// year and month must be the same, repeat for day.
if (day2 < day1)
    return 1;
if (day1 < day2)
    return -1;
return 0; // exact match
```

Answer (score 0):

//You can try this

```
int lday,lmonth,lyear;
int nday,nmonth,nyear;
int lhour,lminute;
int nhour,nminute;
sscanf(New_Time,"%d-%d",&nhour,&nminute); //reads the numbers
sscanf(Last_Time,"%d-%d",&lhour,&lminute); //from the string
sscanf(New_Date,"%d-%d-%d",&nday,&nmonth,&nyear);
sscanf(Last_Date,"%d-%d-%d",&lday,&lmonth,&lyear);
//cout << "Last date: " << lday << "-" << lmonth << "-" << lyear  <<endl;
//cout << "New date: " << nday << "-" << nmonth << "-" << nyear  <<endl;

if(nyear>lyear)
    return 0;
if(nyear==lyear) {
    if(nmonth > lmonth)
        return 0;
    if (nmonth == lmonth) {
        if(nday > lday)
            return 0;
        if (nday == lday) {
            if( nhour > lhour)
                return 0;
            if( nhour == lhour) {
                if(nminute>lminute) {
                    //cout << "new time >= last time" << endl <<endl;
                    return 0;
                }
                else return 1;
            }
            else return 1;
        }
        else return 1;
    }
    else return 1;
}
else return 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Day
{
    int value;

    explicit Day(int value)
    {
        this->value = value;
    }
};

struct Month
{
    int value;

    explicit Month(int value)
    {
        this->value = value;
    }
};

struct Year
{
    int value;

    explicit Year(int value)
    {
        this->value = value;
    }
};

class Date {
public:
    Date(Day newDay, Month newMonth, Year newYear)
    {
        _day = newDay.value;
        _month = newMonth.value;
        _year = newYear.value;
    }

    int GetYear() const {
        return _year;
    };
    int GetMonth() const {
        return _month;
    };
    int GetDay() const {
        return _day;
    };

private:
    int _year;
    int _month;
    int _day;
};    

bool operator < (const Date& lhs, const Date& rhs)
    {
        if (lhs.GetYear() == rhs.GetYear()) {
            if (lhs.GetMonth() == rhs.GetMonth()) {
                if (lhs.GetDay() == rhs.GetDay()) {
                    return false;
                }
    
                return lhs.GetDay() < rhs.GetDay();
            }
    
            return lhs.GetMonth() < rhs.GetMonth();
        }
    
        return lhs.GetYear() < rhs.GetYear();
    };
```